# checkbox as dynamically code in flex grid

Tags: vb.net

I am adding check box inside flex grid in VB 2010 dynamically using find like this

Dim chk box as Check Box= C Type (Me.Controls.Find("CheckBox1", True). First(), Check Box)

I need check box inside grid..instead getting text "Windows.Form.Control.Check Box"
How to get control???